# remove rows containing NA based on condition

Tags: r, dplyr

`df <- data.frame(x = 1:7, y = c(NA, NA, 5, 10, NA, 20, 30))`

From df I want to remove rows containing NA in y based on the condition that the x value in that row is smaller than the x value in the row with the minimum y value to obtain this data frame.

`data.frame(x = 3:7, y = c(5, 10, NA, 20, 30))`

dlypr() solutions preferable!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could use `which.min` to get the index of minimum 'y' value, subset the 'x' create the comparison with the 'x' values along with the expression for NA elements in 'y' and negate (`!`)

```
subset(df,  !(x< x[which.min(y)] & is.na(y)))
```

-output

```
 x  y
3 3  5
4 4 10
5 5 NA
6 6 20
7 7 30
```

---

Or the same logic can be applied with `dplyr::filter`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
    filter(!(x< x[which.min(y)] & is.na(y)))
```

-ouptut

```
 x  y
1 3  5
2 4 10
3 5 NA
4 6 20
5 7 30
```

#### data

```
df <- structure(list(x = 1:7, y = c(NA, NA, 5, 10, NA, 20, 30)), 
class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-7L))
```

Answer (score 1):

Use logical indices for each of the conditions and combine them with logical AND, `&`:

```
df <- data.frame(x = 1:7, y = c(NA, NA, 5, 10, NA, 20, 30))

i <- is.na(df$y)
j <- df$x < df$y
df[!i & j, ]
#  x  y
#3 3  5
#4 4 10
#6 6 20
#7 7 30
```